# Bootstrap 3 to 4 update issues - site styles not rendering

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I recently installed bootstrap 4.5.0 on a development project using bootstrap 3.4 initially.

The site style does not work again. I have rebuilt the project and solution. Still same.

The Bootstrap 3 was successfully changed to 4 and it reflects in packages.cs file as well.

What do I need to do to make the styles work well?

Note that it is an MVC application

Comment: BS 3 and BS 4 are different in many ways. The grid breakpoint has changed in name. Some items are removed or added or has another class name. Important is that BS 4 is based on flex and BS 3 is not. Compare for example the `navbar` and `navbar-nav`. BS 3 cannot be upgraded to BS 4 without rebuilding many parts of the template.

Comment: @bron, so basically the template that came with new ASP.NET MVC will not workusing bootstrap 4?

Comment: If it is a BS3 template, I think not. Is there a minimum grid used? For example, col-sm-xx and up do have other breakpoints in BS4

Comment: @bron, thanks, i got it now and i have compared the classes used, most are quiet different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue is a a result of some classes used in the template i was using which is based on BS3 but not existent in BS4

Answer (score 0):

With MVC i always prefer to use CDN links, it will cause a little bit of a delay but it's doing the trick pretty well.

CSS :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

JS, Popper.js, and jQuery :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: The issue i was having is due to some classes used in the layout but not in the Bootstrap 4 content. Thank you